# implementing Google indexing in my App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-index

******This is my Activity implementation in my Android manifest.xml******

```
<activity
    android:name="com.zameen.zameenapp.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />

        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos”
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
        -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is my Activity Class

```
package com.zameen.zameenapp;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;



import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

public class GizmosActivity extends Activity
{
    static final Uri APP_URI = Uri.parse("android-app://com.zameen.zameenapp/http/www.example.com/gizmos");
    static final Uri WEB_URL = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/gizmos/");
    private GoogleApiClient mClient;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_side_menu);
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.APP_INDEX_API).build();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
    }

    @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();



        // Connect your client
        mClient.connect();

        // Define a title for your current page, shown in autocompletion UI
        String title = "App Indexing API Title";

        // Construct the Action performed by the user
       Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);

        // Call the App Indexing API start method after the view has completely rendered
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, viewAction);


      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {


        // Call end() and disconnect the client
        String title = "App Indexing API Title";
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mClient, viewAction);
        mClient.disconnect();


        super.onStop();
      }
     }
```

I am implementing Google indexing in my App,i have already checked that on a specific Url that is www.example.com/gizmos i can easily start my activity  using adb command line.
The problem is that i have to import Action Class Library files that is **import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;** 
But every time i try to add it i get errors and when import the prescribed library files as recommended by Eclipse i receive errors at **AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end** and also at **newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);** I want to import library file for Action class in my GizmosActivity that could resolve the matter.also some one could tell me that my GizmosActivity code as well as manifest is well defined? and how can i test whether its working well
I would highly appreciate the solution

Comment: `But every time i try to add it i get errors` what errors?

Comment: @Qix that includes wrong library of  import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;but its what recommended for implementing  Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);
As using it i can notify the Google that how many times newAction is performed on my app specific page

Comment: Please paste the *actual* errors Java gives you into your original post, is what I'm saying.

Comment: @Qix i am following this tutorial for my app google indexing https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi

Comment: **You're not listening to me.** You say you're getting errors, but **you're not posting the actual errors you're receiving in your post**.

Comment: @Qix and when i try to import import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action; i get the following errors The import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action cannot be resolved its the same import as its recommended in the tutorial for   Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);

Comment: @Qix i mentioned the error is it because of some SDK update issues?kindly review my code too that am i going fine i would appreciate ur help thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the Solution it was because of **google Services Library** was not updated,update the google Services using SDK and then import the Google services project from **Sdk folder extras into your Eclipse** and after that do not forget to add Google services lib in urs project libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, you can let Gradle handle this for you. Simply adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'` (or whatever version you desire) to your app's `build.gradle` (under dependencies) should let you import the App Indexing libraries you need.

Example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    }
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)